# How to add new columns after minus operation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view.When I execute it with pc_no = 123 get these results

```
name |school   |amount
Jone |Cambridge|400
Steve|London   |400
Mark |Koln     |200
paul |Barcelona|700
Harry|Paris    |0
```

When I execute it with other pc_no = 456 get these results

```
name  |school   |amount
Jone  |Cambridge|300
Steve |London   |400
Mark  |Koln     |500    
Harry |Paris    |50
```

What I want to do is to see difference row and amount differences like that

```
name |school    |lastAmount  |FirstAmount |Diff
Jone |Cambridge |400         |300         |100
Mark |Koln      |200         |500         |-300
paul |Barcelona |700         |0           |700 
Harry|Paris     |0           |50          |-50
```

I executed this query to get difference rows

```
select a.name, a.school,a.amount lastAmount, nvl(b.amount,0) FisrstAmount, 
a.amount - b.amount Diff
from
 (
   select name,school,amount from SchemaName.ViewName  where pc_no= 123
    minus
   select name,school,amount from SchemaName.ViewName  where pc_no= 456
  )  a , SchemaName.ViewName  b where
b.invoice_no =456
and a.name=b.name
and a.school=b.school
```

Result:

```
name |school    |lastAmount  |FirstAmount |Diff
Jone |Cambridge |400         |300         |100
Mark |Koln      |200         |500         |-300
Harry|Paris     |0           |50          |-50
```

I did not get Paul record only.

Comment: Maybe a case for CTEs? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "execute it with pc_no", but sounds like a self join could be what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `amount` values from both sets, so `minus` isn't really what you want. This only shows the values from the first table.

You can get this by full outer joining the tables together, excluding those rows where the difference is zero:

```
create table t1 (
  nm     varchar2(30),
  school varchar2(30),
  amount int
);

create table t2 (
  nm     varchar2(30),
  school varchar2(30),
  amount int
);

insert into t1 values ( 'Jone ', 'Cambridge', 300 );
insert into t1 values ( 'Steve', 'London', 400 );
insert into t1 values ( 'Mark',  'Koln', 500 );
insert into t1 values ( 'Harry', 'Paris', 50 );


insert into t2 values ('Jone ', 'Cambridge', 400 );
insert into t2 values ('Steve', 'London', 400 );
insert into t2 values ('Mark', 'Koln', 200 );
insert into t2 values ('paul', 'Barcelona', 700 );
insert into t2 values ('Harry', 'Paris', 0 );

select nm, school, 
       nvl ( t1.amount, 0 ) first_amount, 
       nvl ( t2.amount, 0 ) last_amount,  
       nvl ( t2.amount, 0 ) - nvl ( t1.amount, 0 ) diff
from   (
  select 1 tab, t1.* from t1
) t1 full outer join (
  select 2 tab, t2.* from t2
) t2
using ( nm, school )
where  nvl ( t1.amount, 0 ) - nvl ( t2.amount, 0 ) <> 0;

NM       SCHOOL       FIRST_AMOUNT   LAST_AMOUNT   DIFF   
Jone     Cambridge             300           400    100 
Mark     Koln                  500           200   -300 
paul     Barcelona               0           700    700 
Harry    Paris                  50             0    -50
```

Comment: I am trying it now